# summation of products of combinatorials

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

For any natural number $N$ and $0\le n\le N$ define
$$ 
f(n) = f(n,N) = \frac{1}{(N+1)!} \sum_{\substack{{S\subset \{1,\ldots,N\}} \\ {|S|=n}}} \prod_{s\in S} s. 
$$
(The empty product is interpreted as $1$.)  It is easy to see that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N} f(n) = 1, 
$$ 
so that $f$ may be thought of as a probability distribution.

As $N$ gets large, what is the maximum value of $f(n)$?  What is the value $n_{max}$ where this peak value is attained, and 
what is the distribution of $f$, especially around $n_{max}$?

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many down votes and votes to close. These values are related to Stirling numbers, and the asymptotics are not obvious. Are those voting to close sure there can be no productive answer given, that this question should be closed to block people from answering?

Comment: Start with $avg(\log) \leq \log(avg)$. Then $\log$ of your quantity is bounded below by the average of $\sum_i \log(x_i)$. Dropping the distinctness requirement, that should be close to $n$ times the average of $\log(x_i)$, so $n(\log N - 1)$. That doesn't quite say that your quantity is $\geq (N/e)^{pN}$ but it's a start.

Comment: The problem is not completely clear to me.  Is $\sigma$ really a tuple, or a set?  If it is an ordered tuple then the formula for $C_N^n$ seems off.  If you really want to sum over sets, the limit seems to be zero: the product is at most $N!/(N-n)!$, and the number of sets is at most $2^N$ so the desired quantity is at most $2^N/(N-n)!$.

Comment: Agree with Lucia's first sentence.  I think you want to know the asymptotics of the average value of the product but I don't see why $N!$ is a reasonable normalising factor.

Comment: The comments above suggest some potential improvements.  I suggest this question be put "on hold" pending such improvements, but per @DouglasZare's comment, should be reopened once improved.

Comment: I think the denominator should be (N+1)! - 1.

Comment: I also think that the poster is interested in (some normalized version of) the shape of the plot (i, ith sum/(N+1)!), as it is clear  f_n as defined goes to 0 for all n as N goes to infinity, and likely f_(pN) also tends to 0 for any fixed  p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnormalized sums are [unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), the coefficient of $x^{N-n}$ in $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+N).$

For $p=1/2$, this is the central Stirling number of the first kind $3,35,735,22449, ..., S_1(2n-1,n), ...$. See [A129505](http://oeis.org/A129505) which mentions

$$S_1(2n-1,n) \sim \frac{1+2c}{8c\sqrt{-\pi(1+c)}} \bigg(\frac{-8c^2}{e(1+2c)}\bigg)^n n^{n-3/2}$$

where $c=\operatorname{LambertW}(-1,\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{e}}) \sim -1.75643$

in a note updated about a month ago.

---

When you think about this as a probability distribution, it is a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables with probabilities $1/2, 2/3, ... N/(N+1)$. It's easy to read off the mean $N+2-H_{N+1} \approx N-\log N + c_1$ and variance $1/4 + 2/9 + ... + N/(N+1)^2 \approx \log N + c_2$. [Lindeberg's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) is satisfied so the distribution is asymptotically normal.

Each binomial factor is unimodal, so the product is unimodal, so the asymptotic normality with standard deviation asymptotic to $\sqrt{\log N}$ gives asymptotic lower bounds for the maximum probability asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \log N}},$ which agrees with The Masked Avenger's heuristics in the comments. I think there should be asymptotic upper bounds of the same form.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please note that I re-wrote the question a bit. I hope now it is more clearer for other readers. Do you know the asymptotic behavior around $n_{\max}$?

Comment: Note that the Nth sum normalized is 1/N+1, the previous is about log N (really $H_N$) times that, and the next previous about (log N)/2 times that, suggesting that n_max is near N - log N.

Comment: Again this is rough heuristics, but I expect the asymptotic value you seek is something near 1/sqrt(2pi log(N)), maybe with 2pi replaced by something larger.

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem already has an accepted answer, this may be a useful connection.  As Douglas Zare notes the problem asks for an understanding of the coefficients of $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+N)$.  Now the $x^k$-th coefficient of the polynomial $x(x+1)\cdots(x+N)$ counts the number of permutations in $S_{N+1}$ with $k$ cycles.  The distribution of the number of cycles in a random permutation has been extensively studied, and is well known to be Gaussian with mean about $\log N$ and variance about $\log N$ (by work of Goncharov 
from the 1940s).  Thus, in the notation of the problem $f(n)$ is the probability that a 
random element of $S_{N+1}$ has $N+1-n$ cycles.